# Fitting TfidfVectorizer - AttributeError / TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization, tf-idf

I'm still growing in my knowledge of Python and am stuck with the TfidfVectorizer.  I've looked at some of the other questions but have not found anything which helped me so far.

I'm trying to create a tfidf_matrix for a list of product descriptions but I am failing.

Here is my code:

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Make tokens per line

dataset = pd.read_csv('Cleansed Data.csv', delimiter=';', encoding='latin1')
tokens = dataset['Description'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
tokens_line = pd.DataFrame(np.array(tokens).reshape(len(tokens), 1), 
columns=['tokens'])
tokens_line_lists = tokens_line.values.tolist()    

# Get unique tokens

Filename = open('descriptions for tokens.txt')
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(Filename)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
tokens_unique = pd.DataFrame(np.array(vocab).reshape(len(vocab), 1), 
columns=['tokens'])

#TF-IDF Vectoriser

tfidf_vectoriser = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=20000, 
min_df=0.2, use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokens_unique, ngram_range=(1,3))

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectoriser.fit_transform(tokens_line)
```

I've tried doing the fit_transform with(tokens) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

With fit_transform with(tokens_line) I get:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

With fit_transform with(tokens_line_lists) I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: What format is 'descriptions for tokens.txt' in?

Comment: both Cleaned Data.csv and descriptions for tokens.txt are the same pieces of text.  Both are mixtures of letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

dataset = pd.read_csv('Cleansed Data.csv', encoding='latin1')
tokenlinelist = dataset['Description'].tolist()

tfidf_vectoriser = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=20000, 
min_df=0.2, use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,3))

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectoriser.fit_transform(tokenlinelist)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get KeyError: 'Description'.  I thought that the TfidfVecotorizer needed to have distinct tokens given to it?

Comment: KeyError: Description just means your data is missing a field named description that the script is trying to reference.  I don't have your data so I can't see what you are reading in.  Since you used 'Description' in line 10 of your code; I assumed your data had a column entitled that.  From the documentation; I believe you only need to give it tokens if you don't want to use its default tokenizer.

Comment: That is the odd thing, it does have a column called Description.  I can't share the data but it is a CSV file with two columns "Part Number" and "Description".

Comment: Immediately after reading in the csv, try:  print(list(dataset)).  Does "Description" appear in the list of column headers?

Comment: Thank you, I checked that and saw that the delimiter was missing in the initial upload.  Once I added that it was OK.